# Can't access to nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to show some data in AngularJS app.

I get JSON from API and show "parent" value. I do this with ng-repat and this is ok, but when user clicks on this value from ng-repeat, I need to show collapsable data bellow, but I can't access in the second level from my JSON.

```
<div class="logBox" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 250px;">
  <div class="list" ng-repeat="(key, value) in lists">

    <a ng-click="collapseIt($index)">{{key}}</a>
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="list in value track by list.id">
      <div ng-if="collapseId==$index">
        <span>
              <img class="logImg" ng-if="list.priority == 0" src="" alt="success" />
              <img class="logImg" ng-if="list.priority == 1" src="" alt="warning" />
              <img class="logImg" ng-if="list.priority == 2" src="" alt="error" />
         </span>
        <span>
               <strong>{{list.update_dt}}</strong>
               </span>
        <span>{{list.type}}</span>
        <span>{{list.serial_number}}</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

And js

```
$scope.collapseIt = function(id) {
    $scope.collapseId = ($scope.collapseId == id) ? -1 : id;
}
```

Here is what I've tried: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2786/)

How to access to this file?

Comment: I'm not sure but you're probably looking for `ng-if="collapseId==$parent.$parent.$index"`

Comment: Your fiddle throws 'Token 'track' is an unexpected token at' probably because of old angular version.

Comment: This seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/y2fg392b/

Comment: @emed it is not duplicated. I don't need ng-if... i need two ng-repeat, one inside another.